# How to change a search direction in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, search

I'm under OS X El Capitan 10.11.1. When I try to search in terminal text by <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> it starts to search from the beginning rather than from the end backwards as it was in terminal on Ubuntu.

So how can I change the search direction to start a search from the end in terminal?

Comment: Maybe not a solution, but just like with most applications, `Cmd+G` repeats  last search and `Cmd+Shift+G` does the same thing, but in the other direction. I think third party terminal applications might give you more control. I believe [iTerm](https://www.iterm2.com/), by default, starts searching from bottom upwards.

Comment: @Joonas, thanks a lot for the reply. Indeed it's not pure solution but it's something that can help

Answer (score 3):

- press <kbd>Cmd-F</kbd>
- to search backward press <kbd>Shift-Enter</kbd>